# Display pointer cursor when hovering paperjs item

Tags: paperjs

I would like the mouse cursor to be a pointer when hovering a `Paper.js` item.
I have found nothing allowing this in the [documentation](http://paperjs.org/reference/global/).
Is that possible ?

[image: expected display when mouse is out]

[image: expected display when mouse is in]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible by setting the [CSS cursor property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) of the canvas element.
You can set it to `pointer` when mouse enter the item and set it back to `default` when mouse leave the item.

Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.11.8/S/nZJNa8MwDIb/isjFKcvSXgYjO5bBDhsUtlvbg+coi1fXKv5IV0r/++w4DS3bqYFA9Fqv9MTSMdN8i1mVvW/QiTYrMkF1jKdTqA3fAwchjVC4MiutcQ8L7tpy3kv5MYoQHoHaoamgk7gvU1CczwyvpbcVPMxGqZFKzUlRcDAyXH8hG89CX9KwJW8R+kJlWZ7PSL9F/Tk1a7wWTpLOJzCCDBWCx6IDwXXHLQhvLBlwBDuS0XuZ3SOjwm1oVlp3UBitC0M7NO6Qs2RmBbDBzCZPZ//pX2qFvMO/1K9Rvom6xoZ75W6i1l6pC+D4cUpxfOOQpd0pfgCprTO+RxtHHX/4A3/cxaApXIF2YW4v1GGga3HYjwhqEZOS0EV7Pdr+Aq+WBO5gOSvg/nG2HrO+vXWykYJHlNAoZbKBPCzop0G+6WvZrFquT78=) demonstrating the solution.

```
// draw a circle
new Path.Circle({
    center: view.center,
    radius: 50,
    fillColor: 'orange',
    // on mouse enter...
    onMouseEnter: function() {
        // ...set canvas cursor to pointer
        view.element.style.setProperty('cursor', 'pointer');
    },
    // on mouse leave...
    onMouseLeave: function() {
        // ...set canvas cursor to default
        view.element.style.setProperty('cursor', null);
    }
});

// display instruction
new PointText({
    content: 'Hover the circle to see the cursor change',
    point: view.center + [0, -80],
    justification: 'center'
});
```